# Navigate to project in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to navigate directly to a project in Visual Studio (2010), or otherwise search-and-find?

I can't >open Project.Name.csproj. Find Project.Name works but isn't very direct, and takes a while on large solutions -- and I still need to have navigate-to-file-in-solution-explorer checked in the options to identify the file, then get to the project.

In ReSharper can use ctrl-shift-T.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> ([Navigate To](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/01/20/how-to-use-navigate-to-vstiptool0006.aspx)). And you can install the [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/) which gives you most features of the Visual Studio 2012 Solution Explorer (using the [Solution navigator](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/07/20/solution-navigator-blog-post.aspx)). There's a <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> shortcut which takes you directly to the search/filter bar of the Solution Navigator.

Answer (score 1):

You can create links to your frequently used projects and navigate to them in Solution Explorer with the [Favorite Documents](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d4ab8421-147f-4416-8038-d5f7fdcf6a56) extension.

Answer (score 0):

To navigate to project file(*.csproj) from Visual Studio,

**First Way**

1. First Go to "Folder View" from the top options in Solution Explorer.
2. Navigate to project
3. Double click, or open *.csproj

**Second Way**

We can not load .csproj file while we loading it in Solution.
So, easy and quick way,

1. Unload project from Solution View.
2. Double click or open the unloaded project.